# Python Not Finding Module

Tags: python, python-import

Given the following python project, created in PyDev:

```
├── algorithms
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── neighborhood
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── neighbor
│       │   ├── connector.py
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── manager.py
│       │   └── references.py
│       ├── neighborhood.py
│       ├── tests
│       │   ├── fixtures
│       │   │   └── neighborhood
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       └── web
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── service.py
├── configuration
│   ├── Config.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── __init__.py
└── webtrack
    |- teste.py
    ├── .gitignore
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manager
        ├── Data.py
        ├── ImportFile.py
        └── __init__.py
```

We've been trying with no success to import modules from one folder to another, such as:

```
from algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector import NeighborhoodConnector
```

Which yields the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "teste.py", line 49, in <module>
from algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector import NeighborhoodConnector
ImportError: No module named algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector
```

We tried to append its path to the sys.path variable but with no success.

We also tried to use os.walk to insert all paths into PATH variable but still we get the same error, even though we checked PATH does contain the path to find the modules.

We are using Python 2.7 on Linux Ubuntu 13.10.

Is there anything we could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you verified how far along the import chain the problem occurs?  That is, does `import algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector` fail?  What about `import algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor`, `import algorithms.neighborhood`, and `import algorithms`?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @BrenBarn We tried what you suggested and got the same error

Comment: @AaronDigulla Python 2

Comment: Where is "teste.py" in your project tree?

Comment: @dyoo it's on the webtrack folder (we by mistake deleted it when posting)

Comment: Is the top level of your project (the level above the unnamed top level package that you've shown) in `sys.path`? If so, then you should be able to use absolute imports like: `from your_package.algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector import NeighborhoodConnector`. Or, if you're executing your script correctly (using `-m` with `sys.path` set up right, or by a relative path from the top level folder) you should be able to use an explicit relative import: `from ..algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector import NeighborhoodConnector`

Comment: @Blckknght Inserting our higher folder (named recsys) into our sys.path and trying for the absolute import yielded the error:
/usr/bin/python: No module named recsys.algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector
Not sure why it printed "/usr/bin/python", but it didn't work

Comment: For me it was as simple as using VS Code - and adding new file.. It put it into a subfolder rather than the project folder and totally borked the import! Facepalm!

Answer (score 16):

Getting imports right when running a script that lives within a package is tricky. You can read [this section of the (sadly deferred) PEP 395](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#why-are-my-imports-broken) for a description of a bunch of ways that don't work to run such a script.

Give a file system hierarchy like:

```
top_level/
    my_package/
        __init__.py
        sub_package/
            __init__.py
            module_a.py
            module_b.py
            sub_sub_package/
                __init__.py
                module_c.py
        scripts/
            __init__.py
            my_script.py
            script_subpackage/
                 __init__.py
                 script_module.py
```

There are only a few ways to make running `my_script.py` work right.

1. The first would be to put the `top_level` folder into the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or use a `.pth` file to achieve the same thing. Or, once the interpreter is running, insert that folder into `sys.path` (but this can get ugly).

   Note that you're adding `top_level` to the path, not `my_package`! I suspect this is what you've got messed up in your current attempts at this solution. Its very easy to get wrong.

   Then, absolute imports like `import my_package.sub_package.module_a` will mostly work correctly. (Just don't try importing `package.scripts.my_script` itself while it is running as the `__main__` module, or you'll get a weird duplicate copy of the module.)

   However, absolute imports will always be more verbose than relative imports, since you always need to specify the full path, even if you're importing a sibling module (or "niece" module, like `module_c` from `module_a`). With absolute imports, the way to get `module_c` is always the big, ugly mouthful of code `from my_package.sub_package.sub_sub_package import module_c` regardless of what module is doing the importing.
2. For that reason, using relative imports is often more elegant. Alas, they're hard to get to work from a script. The only ways are:

   1. Run `my_script` from the `top_level` folder with the `-m` flag (e.g. `python -m my_package.scripts.my_script`) and never by filename.

      It won't work if you're in a different folder, or if you use a different method to run the script (like pressing F5 in an IDE). This is somewhat inflexible, but there's not really any way to make it easier (until PEP 395 gets undeferred and implemented).
   2. Set up `sys.path` like for absolute imports (e.g. add `top_level` to `PYTHONPATH` or something), then use a [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) `__package__` string to tell Python what the expected package of your script is. That is, in `my_script.py` you'd want to put something like this above all your relative imports:

      ```
      if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
          __package__ = "my_package.my_scripts"
      ```

      This will require updating if you reorganize your file organization and move the script to a different package (but that's probably less work than updating lots of absolute imports).

   Once you've implemented one of those soutions, your imports can get simpler. Importing `module_c` from `module_a` becomes `from .sub_sub_package import module_c`. In `my_script`, relative imports like `from ..subpackage import module_a` will just work.

Comment: Thanks Blcknght! Could you explain a bit why set the top_level/ instead of my_package/ to the PYTHONPATH? Is it the higher the better or just one level on top of the actual whole package?

Comment: It's just one level above the real package. When you do `import my_package`, Python will check every folder in PYTHONPATH to see if it contains a file name `my_package.py` or a folder named `my_package` with an `__init__.py` file in it.

Comment: "run as a module and never by filename" works for me

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but still I am going to post my solution.

Had a similar issue. Just added the paths with the following line before importing the package:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')) 
from lib import create_graph
```

Answer (score 1):

The way imports work is slightly different in Python 2 and 3. First Python 3 and the sane way (which you seem to expect). In Python 3, all imports are relative to the folders in `sys.path` ([see here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for more about the module search path). Python doesn't use `$PATH`, by the way.

So you can import anything from anywhere without worrying too much.

In Python 2, imports are relative and sometimes absolute. The [document about packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) contains an example layout and some import statements which might be useful for you.

The section "[Intra-package References](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)" contains information about how to import between packages.

From all the above, I think that your `sys.path` is wrong. Make sure the folder which *contains* `algorithms` (i.e. *not* `algorithms` itself but it's parent) needs to be in `sys.path`

Comment: Trying to insert into teste.py the line `from ..algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector import NeighborhoodConnector` yeilded the error:
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package.
Did something wrong? All __init__.py files are present

Comment: That's really weird. 1. You can debug imports that work with `python -v` but not the ones which fail. Try it anyway. 2. Maybe there is a typo in one of the `__init__.py` files? 3. Check again that `sys.path` contains the correct values. Maybe try to load the module manually: http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Answer (score 1):

Just set `__package__ = None` in **every** .py file. It will setup all the package hierarchy automatically.

After that you may freely use absolute module names for import.

```
from algorithms.neighborhood.neighbor.connector import NeighborhoodConnector
```