# How do I set up imports for custom modules in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to bring my (working/executable) project from PyCharm to VS Code. My folder structure looks like this (simplified):

```
root
|- .venv
|- src
 |- helper
 |- windows
  |- main
   |- __init__.py
   |- main_window.py
 |- __init__.py
```

I'm trying to execute the src/__init__.py file, which has the following code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from src.windows.main import MainWindow
import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works perfectly in PyCharm, but VS Code gives me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I've tried numerous solutions from the internet (Stack Overflow and official VS Code documentation), including modifying settings.json and launch.json. Currently my JSONs look like this:

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}\\src"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.json (User):

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Classic Icons",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "editor.letterSpacing": 1,
    "editor.lineHeight": 27,
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Roboto Mono', monospace",
    "editor.fontWeight": "300",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Classic",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Inconsolata', monospace",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 18,
    "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,
    "bracket-pair-colorizer-2.colors": [
        "White"
    ]
}
```

settings.json (Workspace):

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "c:\\Users\\username\\PycharmProjects\\Snake_It_Off\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true
}
```

However, I'm still getting the error. Is this a VS Code issue? In PyCharm, I could just mark several folders as sources (and it automatically detected any folder containing __init__.py as a module). How do I correctly set up the project to be able to run it?

Comment: How are you trying to execute it exactly?

Comment: Using the Run button in VS Code, also tried using the Code Runner extension (see other comments in this thread). Both methods yield the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem. I had to move my main executable file, src/__init__.py, outside of the src folder, since executing a script from withing a package [can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972669/python-not-finding-module). Another important step was double-checking that my PYTHONPATH is set correctly by running the following code:

```py
import sys

print(sys.path)
```