# I Can't import custom python modules in VS code

Tags: python, import, python-import, visual-studio-code

My code structure is:

```
- project
| -__init__.py
| - module.py
| - module2.py
```

In `module2.py` I try importing the functions from `module.py` using: `from project.module import func1` However, I get the error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'`

This same code runs perfectly on PyCharm. I have already tried adding `"env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}` to `launch.json`, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Did yoy tried "from module import func1" ?

Comment: Importing the module directly works. The only problem is that all existing projects I work on make the imports in this same style:`project.module`

Comment: This link can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441104/how-do-i-set-up-imports-for-custom-modules-in-vs-code

Comment: Try to create a .env file and define a variable PYTHONPATH=project in this file.