# mac: using python 3 via pyenv throws import errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-import, pyenv

## What does not work

Have been trying to setup python 3.8.5 on mac using pyenv as described by [Matthew Broberg](https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-we-should-do)

```sh
$ brew install pyenv && pyenv install 3.8.5
```

**.zshrc**

```
# Python
# https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-we-should-do
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# Pip - https://gist.github.com/haircut/14705555d58432a5f01f9188006a04ed
PATH="$PATH:~/Library/Python/2.7/bin"
PATH="$PATH:~/Library/Python/3.8.5/bin"
```

doing

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

but running scripts like

```sh
$ python utils/search.py 'something' 'somewhere'
Traceback (most recent call last):
__file__=utils/search.py                     | __name__=__main__             | __package__=None                
  File "utils/search.py", line 9, in <module>
    import utils.constants as CONSTANTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

## What works

removing pyenv by `brew uninstall pyenv && rm -Rf ~/.pyenv` and completely restarting the terminal (sourcing `.zshrc` does not seem to be enough).

```sh
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
$ python3 utils/search.py 'something' 'somewhere'
Found what you are looking for. It's working!
$
```

## What I don't understand

It's the same python version, but I'm getting import errors in one of them - how does that makes sense?

And more importantly: **Can I fix it so python 3 is the default for terminal `python` and not having to use `python3`**

BTW: alias `python` to `python3` is not an option - tried it and recall it was a failure.

Comment: This is not a problem of the python version, but how you are running the "script". ``python`` still refers to python3, but ``utils`` is not in the module search path. You should likely be running ``python3 -m utils.search`` instead. Note that it is not possible to definitely answer this without knowing what ``utils`` is, and how it was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you didn't describe your problem correctly. Not related to `pyenv` but the way how another package is imported.

Explanation about the how the `import` works in Python: [Python Not Finding Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19992499/5101148)

Python depends the `sys.path` to import packages. It searches the path in `sys.path` and try to find the package you want.

In my understanding, when you call `python utils/search.py`, `$PWD/utils` is added into `sys.path` but not `$PWD`. There's no way to get the command working cause module `utils` is not covered by `$PWD/utils` but `$PWD`.

**Solution**: `touch utils/__init__.py` and call `python -m utils.search 'something' 'somewhere'`.